# Nullable field with Non-nullable getter

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement non-nullable getter with nullable setter and nullable field.

1. Field `parent` can be null, which means that the parent is `this`. If parent is not null, the parent is the `parent` value.
2. Getter is not-nullable as it either returns `this` or `parent`
3. Setter can set nullable value as it can remove the current parent.

I tried this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
var _parent: T? = null
var parent: T
    get() = if (isParent) this as T else _parent!!
    set(value) {
        _parent = if (value == null) null else value.parent
    }
```

I don't like the `_parent` variable, but also it doesn't help with the setter, because it is still not-nullable as the `parent: T`, so the solution does not work.

Comment: I don't know what ORM you're using but chances are it's extending/implementing this abstract class/interface, so `parent` will be just another property. You better make `parent` an extension property if you want to supply any custom logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At this time it's not possible to define a property with different getter and setter types. There is an [open feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4075) for this functionality, but it's not planned for any specific Kotlin version.

Comment: so what would you actually do in my case? what would be the correct solution at this moment?

Comment: In your case, you are not allowed to take advantage of the property feature of kotlin (because of said difference in nullability) and must actually define a getParent and setParent method signature explicitly. And invoke them the java way of .getParent() and .setParent(foo).